# FileMaker Webviewer

Tags: javascript, html, filemaker

I have the following problem. I built a website with html and javascript. The website works. A component of the website is an API from vis.js. Now I have the problem that my website is not displayed in the webviewer of FileMaker (I tried with WebSource and with the url of my website). Can someone tell me why? I suspect it's because FileMaker is accessing Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer is out of date and can no longer run a lot properly.
The first picture is from FileMaker. The second one is runed by google chrome[image]
[image]

Comment: Without seeing your code, all you can get is guesses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701334/14945732

Comment: Web viewer is using webkit. Also, it uses iFrame to render pages which might mess with your code. Finally, as Michael said, it is hard to say anything without looking at your code

Answer (score 1):

On Microsoft Windows 10, the latest version of FileMaker Pro 19, the `webviewer`component uses the Microsoft Edge (Chromium) instead of the Internet Explorer (IE) engine to render web content.

This is a recent move, only available since version 19.3.1 of the product, [ref. available here](https://community.claris.com/en/s/article/Claris-FileMaker-Pro-19-3-1-Release-Notes).

From what I can see, you are working on FileMaker Pro 19 version, but you may need to check the minor version, as if you work with 19.1.x or 19.2.x, you are still using the IE engine.

While developing any project, the platform it has to be deployed to must be clearly identified from the beginning. In the previous versions of FileMaker, we still are using by default IE 9 or IE 11 for the `webviewer` component. It was possible to select the IE engine by changing some Windows registry keys, or with the MBS plugin in order to automate this.

I have tested vis.js with some basic examples:

- FileMaker 17.0.7.700 - renders initial state ony, not working
- FileMaker 18.0.3.317 - renders initial state ony, not working
- FileMaker 19.3.2.206 - all works fine

> If you use an older version of FileMaker, consider using an older
> version of vis.js.
>
> If you need the latest version of vis.js, upgrade your FileMaker to at
> least 19.3.1.